# Get Device absolute path in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I'm using Phonegap 3.3.0, earlier i used 2.5.0 where entry.fullPath will give the Device full path. 
These paths would typically look like

```
/var/mobile/Applications/<application UUID>/Documents/path/to/file  (iOS)
/storage/emulated/0/path/to/file                                    (Android)
```

since that method is deprecated am using entry.toURL() method to get the path.This method will now return filesystem URLs of the form

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file
```

In My application, am passing the URL to Native function and from native am opening a file. But If I pass the path to Native, iOS could not able to detect the file. The same If i hardcode the Absolute path, application detects the file.

How to use the fileSystem URL to access the file in native or any other method to get the device absolute path ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("device is ready");
    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function fail() {
    console.log("failed to get filesystem");
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    console.log("got filesystem");

        // save the file system for later access
    console.log(fileSystem.root.fullPath);
    window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
}

function downloadImage(url, fileName){
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.download(
        url,
        window.rootFS.fullPath + "/" + fileName,
        function(entry) {
            console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);

        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("download error" + error.code);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Use fileSystem.root.nativeURL

Answer (score 7):

The `toURL()` method or the `nativeURL` attribute should return the result wanted:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
    console.log("fileSystem.root.toURL()="+fileSystem.root.toURL());
    console.log("fileSystem.root.toInternalURL()="+fileSystem.root.toInternalURL());
    console.log("fileSystem.root.nativeURL="+fileSystem.root.nativeURL);
}, function(){
    alert("fails!");
});
```

Using cordova 3.5, the output in iPad simulator is:

```
fileSystem.root.toURL()=file:///Users/myuser/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/1717CB5F-4032-45C7-8CA2-342502447F36/Documents/
fileSystem.root.toInternalURL()=cdvfile://localhost/persistent/
fileSystem.root.nativeURL=file:///Users/myuser/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/1717CB5F-4032-45C7-8CA2-342502447F36/Documents/
```

...and in Android simulator (Genymotion) is:

```
fileSystem.root.toURL()=file:///storage/emulated/0/ 
fileSystem.root.toInternalURL()=cdvfile://localhost/persistent/ 
fileSystem.root.nativeURL=file:///storage/emulated/0/
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you. Just a note for others, this needs to be called when the device is ready: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` and then inside your device ready callback put the  `window.requestFileSystem` call, eg: `function onDeviceReady(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
  alert("entered gotFS: " + fileSystem.root.toURL);
}
```

Comment: This will give path like this cdvfile://localhost/persistent/path/to/file..

I want absolute path